# VS SDK ContentType does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, envdte, visual-studio-sdk

I am trying to include a custom language support for Visual Studio.

To start with, I need to have `GoToDefinition` support. And I am struggling to get the context menu to include this command.

I have defined a `ContentTypeDefinition` and have included the `FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition` such as:

```
internal sealed class GaugeFileContentType
{
    [Export]
    [Name("Gauge")]
    [BaseDefinition("code")]
    internal static ContentTypeDefinition GaugeContentTypeDefinition = null;

    [Export]
    [FileExtension(".spec")]
    [ContentType("Gauge")]
    internal static FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition GaugeFileExtensionDefinition = null;
}
```

Now, despite this, on debugging, I see that `DTE.ActiveDocument.Type` is `text`, despite me adding the `[BaseDefinition('code')]` attribute. What am I missing here?

Are the above definitions enough to tell Visual Studio to bring up Context menu for code?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of head banging, I managed to figure out a way.

I was using the Experimental Instance for debugging, and it did not clean and reinstall the extension, and thus Visual Studio continued to treat the `ContentType` as 'Plain Text', since that was what I had originally.

When I build a VSIX and installed, opened the same file in a new instance of Visual Studio, it brought up the right context menu.

However, it brought out more than what I wanted (i.e `Run Unit Tests` from Resharper). So I did some more digging up.

In order to ensure that Visual Studio can handle a command, it checks for it by calling [`IOleCommandTarget.QueryStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.iolecommandtarget.querystatus.aspx) method.

All I had to do was set the CommandFlag as `(uint)OLECMDF.OLECMDF_ENABLED | (uint)OLECMDF.OLECMDF_SUPPORTED` and return `VSConstants.S_OK` when the `cmdId` is `VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.GotoDefn`.

The final method looks like this:

```
public int QueryStatus(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint cCmds, OLECMD[] prgCmds, IntPtr pCmdText)
{
    if ((VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID)prgCmds[0].cmdID == VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.GotoDefn)
    {
        prgCmds[0].cmdf = (uint)OLECMDF.OLECMDF_ENABLED | (uint)OLECMDF.OLECMDF_SUPPORTED;
        return VSConstants.S_OK;
    }
    return Next.QueryStatus(pguidCmdGroup, cCmds, prgCmds, pCmdText);
}
```